# SSRS Reporting — What is in a NULL?

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, null

Beginners question for you: in an SSRS Report (Visual Studio 2008) when a parameter that accepts Null values is set to Null, what does it actually contain?

```
NULL
''
```

Or something else?

In particular I am curious what 2008 R2 sees when it receives that parameter.

Comment: *a parameter that excepts Null values is set to Null*...What does that mean?

Comment: Null, and setting something to null is used in every language I have come across so far. But it does not explicitly mean the same thing in every language. These are the potential options I am familiar with.

NULL
0
''
""
FALSE (might be mis-remembering that)

Comment: I would recommend running a SQL trace and seeing what is coming across.  SSMS > Tools > SQL Server Profiler , connect to your server, pick the tsql template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NULL` simply means that a value hasn't been assigned. So it is the lack of a value rather than an actual value.

In particular, the empty string is not Null, it is a string that has been assigned the value of a zero-length string, which is different to not having a value at all. Same for numeric values - `Null` doesn't mean `0` which is a specific numeric value, it means no value at all has been assigned. For example, if you had a field called `Siblings` which was the number of siblings a person has, if the field had `0` we would know that they have no siblings; however, if the field is `Null` it means we don't know how many siblings they have.

For booleans, being nullable turns them from a binary operator with the possible values `True` and `False` to a ternary operator with the possible values `True`, `False` and `Unknown`.

Evaluating something to `Null` is always false, so you can't use `=` to evaluate it, you must use `IS` like so: `WHERE Something IS Null`.

A good trick to use with null parameters where you want everything if the parameter is `Null` is to use both a test for null and a test for value in your `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE ((@Param IS Null) OR (SomeField = @Param))
```

Here if the parameter has no value (i.e. is `Null`) you will get everything; otherwise if the parameter has a value it will return those rows where it equals `SomeField`.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass a NULL value to a parameter then that is what it will contain. However in SSRS expressions NULL is referred to as "Nothing", as in:

```
IsNothing(Parameter.Value)

Parameter.Value Is Nothing
```